Running mysql through conda
I installed mysql (version 8.4.0) through conda. However mysql -u root -p prompts me for a password and neither root nor empty string work.
The top answer here suggested doing sudo mysql first. However this returns the error command not found (even though it's there in the environment).

What's going on and how do I find the root?
Edit: Using which mysql gives the correct path to the conda environment bin folder:

Have you tried using sudo /path/to/mysql where /path/to/mysql is the result returned from which mysql? I think for some reasons the mysql binary doesn't exist in sudo's PATH variable

Yes. That gave me a user is not allowed to execute as root on pop-os. But then how do I set up a password for mysql (without doing sudo mysql) as per the linked query?

I think then the user you're running the command is not in sudo group. Is this your school/company machine? If not, I think you can follow the step in this answer to add your user to sudo group

Yes it is a school machine. I'm connected using ssh

come to think of it, what package did you use to install mysql through conda? If I remember right, conda only has mysql-connector-python for Python mysql interface instead of mysql client on shell interface

If you do conda search mysql you get a bunch of packages including 8.4.0.

I get ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2) when entering a password.
